# Is the opacity and alpha the same thing for UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opacity, alpha

I want to use animation to change UIView's color to make it fade, however, somehow i can't access and set opacity, but i can set alpha. I wonder if alpha and opacity are the same? Search on the web and I didnt find a good answer. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Actually "opacity" means "value of alpha-channel" of your `UIView`. When a view is fully opaque this means its `alpha = 1`, when a view is fully transparent (non-opaque) its `alpha = 0`.

As about properties of `CALayer` and `UIView` in Cocoa, yes, they provide the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks Alex! And I realized to access alpha is easier than access opacity in coding, since the latter one requires import the QuartzCore lib.

Comment: What is the preferred way?
`view.alpha` vs `view.layer.opacity`?

Comment: If both things are same and one is easier to set. You can choose which one you prefer. For me Alpha is preferred way.

Answer (score 13):

Just try by yourself!

`CALayer` has `opacity` from 0 to 1, while `UIView` has `alpha` from 0 to 1. They have the same visual effect.

Comment: They do have same visual effect, however is there any performance impact in using either of the way of coding?

Answer (score 8):

Alpha affects everything drawn on the view.The background color's alpha  affects the background color's transparency and anything else drawn on the view.i.e it brings about a frosty effect to whole view. Opacity means don't draw anything underneath, even if you are transparent, it just effects the current view.

Comment: It doesn't impact subviews, so not quite 'everything drawn on the view' - from Apple's docs: *"This value affects only the current view and does not affect any of its embedded subviews"*

Comment: I think there is another confusion...There is a field called "BOOL Opaque" which has some description about how it will affect subviews...